# Maintenance on large logging files in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, log

I was running into an issue with the `system.log` and some custom log files getting way to large to find anything or even to open them.

Normally we don't run logs on live webshops but in this case it was necessary. This resulted in log files reaching sizes of several hundred Mb.

I'm looking for a solution where, just like Apaches logs the files are split up by day and only retained for X days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created an extension that implements log rotation (in my case daily) and cleans them up after 20 days using a Magento cron job. Both settings you can change from the `System > Configuration > System > Log cleaning`

You can get it from https://github.com/sandermangel/rklogrotate. Feel free to let me know if you have tips or suggestions.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, if you can configure log rotate using cronjobs please do. If not, this extension might be a nice second-best

Comment: Link doesnt worky anymore. Can you please update?

Answer (score 7):

I personally prefer to just use logrotate to rotate, gzip and delete the logs.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, in your case a simple cronjob would do the trick I guess packing and deleting files each day. To do this from the extension would be overkill.

Comment: yes, just configure logrotate, put it in a cronjob and it does what you want, but be careful, we just missconfigured it and hat millions of files because the count of them raises exponentially each day :-)

Comment: I fully recommend using logrotate - this is a devops thing, isn't it? :)

Comment: Yes, absolutely, not our problem :D

Comment: The irony is that "devops" means, it actually IS our problem ;) Here's an example configuration that archives (compresses) each log file after a week and keeps the last three archived versions for each. Wildcards come in handy for multiple sites and multiple log files: `/var/www/*/htdocs/var/log/*.log { \n
    compress \n
    weekly \n
    rotate 3 \n
}` (`\n` for line break)

Answer (score 1):

Put this in `/etc/logrotate.d/magento`

```
/var/www/magesite/var/log/*.log {
        size 10M
        missingok
        rotate 50
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        dateext
        dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
}
```

Source: [fixes.co.za magento2 logrotate](https://fixes.co.za/magento2/magento-2-logrotate-for-logs-getting-large/)